# Целесообразность создания API

Tags: php, архитектура

Планирую создать сервис, который будет отдавать данные по API.

Также будет сайт-клиент, который будет обращаться к этому сервису по API.

**Вопрос**: насколько целесообразно "гонять" данные между API и клиентом без какого-либо кэширования на клиенте? Запросов предполагается много, возможно несколько миллионов в сутки. API и клиент физически будут расположены на разных серверах на разных континентах.

Делается это с целью того, чтобы не реализовывать каждый раз на сайтах-клиентах функционал, который предоставляет API. Если мой подход не верен, какие есть варианты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Делается это с целью того, чтобы не реализовывать каждый раз на сайтах-клиентах функционал, который предоставляет API.

По-хорошему это значит, что такой сервис должен иметь возможность быть поднятым где угодно рядом с сервисом-клиентом и, с минимальной конфигурацией, обновлять свою БД и прочие данные в автоматическом режиме. В то же время, любое API должно быть рассчитано на безумный поток клиентов, и должно без проблем горизонтально масштабироваться (должен быть беспроблемный ввод новых инстансов, которые, в случае необходимости, должны уметь самореплицироваться); на практике это подразумевает наличие кэша в оперативной памяти, куда скидываются полезные данные из ответов до тех пор, пока не устареют. Это позволяет делать blazing-fast сервисы, которые отвечают за пару миллисекунд; в случае с PHP это будет немного помедленнее (а кэш возможно, будет доставаться по сети), но все равно в пределах десятка миллисекунд и с минимальными накладными расходами. Одно только правильное кэширование (например, нельзя забывать про dogpile-эффект) способно поднять rps до пары тысяч, что позволит одному серверу справиться с вышеописанными миллионами запросов.

Клиент, конечно, тоже должен стремиться минимально использовать API и аналогично кэшировать те данные, которые не должны измениться, но уже по той причине, что API может быть далеко, и обращение к нему тупо удоражает ответ на полсотни миллисекунд за счет времени передачи данных. При этом может быть нарушение целостности данных, но просроченные на пять минут данные не являются чем-то страшным, а теорему cap пока еще никто не обманул. Грамотно настроенная связка сервер-клиент сама будет подсказывать, что и как кэшировать, используя связанные с кэшированием заголовки HTTP.

В принципе же построение stateless-сервисов, которые постоянно пользуются API соседнего сервиса без кэширования - это нормальная практика. API должен быть всегда готов к тому, что к нему придет пара тысяч клиентов, и к горизонтальному масштабированию. Однако в данном случае я бы реализовывал API-сервис как некий сервис-спутник, поднимаемый в пару команд рядом с тем сервисом, который им хочет пользоваться, если, конечно, это возможно.

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ!
На данный момент я отказался от api и развернул сервис рядом с основным приложением на том же сервере, что и приложение. И написал клиент для приложения в виде composer-пакета.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно не целесообразно, получается сайт-донор, который выпивает все соки из "сервиса". Ваша "тачка-сервис" просто ляжет от кол-ва запросов. А если таких сайтов ещё и 10-20, и на каждом по 1М запросов.. Или мощная тачка для "сервиса", или ляжет.

Я использую CI с его кешированием и свою библу для работы апи. Никаких проблем с переносом вообще нет, новый клиент – библа апи и вперёд.

Кешинг работает так: Перед пробросом запроса смотрю кеш-файлик, если он существует – не бросаю запрос, если нет – курлом летит. Если на "серсиве" изменились данные, он бросает запрос на "клиенты" и клиенты просто удаляют кеш-файлик. Зетс олл меджик.

Comment: Вот мне тоже такой вариант предложили с обёрткой для работы с API, которая при обращении будет проверять есть ли данные из кэша и отдавать их, если нет, то обращаться по API. Вариант с изменением данных на сервисе и посыланием запроса на удаление кэша кажется интересным, спасибо)
P.S. CI - это CodeIgniter?

Comment: @PendalF да, всё верно, CI – CodeIgniter. Если ответ правильный – пожалуйста отметьте его как правильный)

Comment: Спасибо, отметил!